# Laravel - How should I create two separate register pages?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, registration, user-registration

What would be the best approach for me to create two registration pages in Laravel 5.2? One should assign the user's role to 'buyer' and the other one to 'seller'.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create two views and pass some variable in registration form, like:

```
{!! Form::hidden('role', 'user') !!}
```

And then change `create()` method in `RegisterController` (if you're using 5.3) or `AuthController` (for 5.2) to something like this:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'role' => $data['role'], // This will set role from hidden form element
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Don't forget to add `role` to [`$fillable`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#mass-assignment) array in `User` model.